# Can a useful, formal system of logic be constructed with no axioms or assumptions, or perhaps using only Occam's razor?

Tags: logic, occams-razor

Can a useful, formal system of logic be constructed with no axioms or assumptions, or perhaps using only Occam's razor?

This may seem a silly and fun question, but what is the most complex proof that can be constructed in such a way?

Suppose nothing exists. Therefore supposition exists; a contradiction. Therefore something exists.

Comment: Natural Deduction has only rules and no axioms.

Comment: Occam's razor is an heuristic principle; do you think to use it as axiom ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA axiom: Occam's razor decides every decision.

Comment: In your proof you have used a [Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) or Indirect Proof, i.e. a logical law or rule of inference.

Comment: Considering that Occam's razor is a selection principle, and  it needs something to select from, no. And existence of a supposition does not follow from "suppose nothing exists" without a whole lot of other suppositions about assertions, figures of speech, etc.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA good point. "Occam's razor decides every decision" was a later thought prompted by your question of what Occam might look like as an axiom.

Comment: @Conifold did assertions, figures of speech etc. precede the Universe?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA either nothing or something exists. Either requires an assumption, therefore doubt exists.

Comment: They certainly precede the concept of the universe, which the word is used to express, and so does a long developmental process to learn how to use it in a sentence. This is why your question is unintelligible until you spell out what "no assumptions" means. Mauro already told you that you can avoid axioms by replacing them with rules or norms, and you need those to be understood. So what is it that you want to avoid exactly, and what does Occam's razor have to do with it?

Comment: From a more modern point of view, there is no reason to separate rules from axioms (or the traditional other alternative 'postulates').  In that case, the law of contradiction itself is an axiom.  So even your example fails.

Comment: @jobermark an illuminating comment, not least because when I ask the same question denying myself access to the law of contradiction, I proceed "...supposition exists. Which would contradict the supposition... which requires that supposition both exists and does not exist, which is weaker under Occam's razor than supposition existing so I choose that something exists.

Comment: @Conifold In answer to your question, the question was motivated by thoughts in their formative stage and with the intention of forming such thoughts further in response to any answers or discussion that ensued.  So I am perhaps a little bit vague on exactly what I want to avoid, but I **think** I want to minimise the things taken to be true in the absence of proof, for any given conclusion.

Comment: Or you can look at non-duality as one less rule to follow, rather than as something that creates multiple simultaneous options.  One Buddhist response would be to ask whether it matters that something exists -- whether it is possible to act differently in a meaningful way that truly depends upon this fact one way or the other, or whether you have no choice but to experience the illusion, even if it is not a fact.  If not, you should not answer the question, because then there is one less answer and one less unnecessary entity.

Comment: Occam's razor often cuts both ways, depending upon how you state something.  The natural duality of options and limitations makes sure this will almost always be the case.

Comment: @jobermark I take your point but I think that tackles the question of whether "anything" exists at all, whereas I used the possibly fatuous example of deduction that "anything" exists at all merely as perhaps a precursor to deducing what things really do exist in a more meaningful sense such as a sense which discriminates between the fact that I do exist and the flying spaghetti monster doesn't. Also, I'm not proposing non-duality as a rule, just that duality is two assumptions vs the one of singularity and therefore weaker by Occam's razor - **ceteris paribus**.

Comment: I am proposing that Occam's razor, at this level suggests non-duality *as a non-rule*.  The supposition that something exists is an entity that is not necessary, it gains us nothing, (since we cannot escape 'maya').  The distinction between fiction and direct experience is not dependent on an ontology, just the experience of storytelling.  So we disagree even at this very first step.  The point is that one's ultimate ontological basis already biases the application of the razor so completely that it is not a reasonable principle to consider basic.

Comment: @jobermark it seems you are proposing to take 'existence' as a given truth, subject to the fatuous question of the illusion of reality, which we gain nothing by considering, all of which I actually agree with but it seems you think I disagree with. But I am saying by this proposed tool of Ocean's Razor we can even take this given fact of existence whose truth is beyond question and assign some explanation of why existence is stronger than nonexistence, such is the power of the theory. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: No, you don't.  I give up.

Comment: The obvious way to minimize premises for a conclusion is to take it as a premise, but that is not very interesting. Occam's razor on its own can not do anything either, it is a device to choose among already available alternatives. I am afraid, the question dissolves without spelling out some more.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the sense in which you mean the word 'useful' -- mathematicians try to make a study of the logical objects which are 'useful' or interesting in some sense, and pretty much any set-theoretic encoding (or type-theoretic encoding) of this information will require assumptions, which are identical to axioms from the standpoint of philosophy of set theory.

Perhaps this is not true by necessity, though. There is currently a development underway that is referred to as the 'reverse mathematics of second-order set theory', which seeks to understand what assumptions are necessary to prove certain well-known theorems in mathematics. This is a reversal of classical mathematics, in the sense that we are moving from a place of

> 'we believe this theorem is true in most reasonable contexts -- what is the bare minimum that we need to assume to prove it so',

as opposed to

> 'here is what we are assuming is true, what are the consequences'.

A development with minimal axiomatic use for maximum proof capability would probably fit somewhere into this hierarchy of assumption strength. I don't know how one would proceed with no assumptions, however -- even your suggestion of Occam's razor is ultimately still just an assumption.

Comment: I'm in favour of this development because all "facts" are in fact only facts based only upon the evidence used to deduce them. This is akin to saying, what is the evidence I must accept as true (axioms), in order to make such a thing (conclusion) true. As regards Occam's razor, sometimes we have apparently conflicting or competing facts. Ultimately I think Occam's razor is the fundamental underlying tool by which we select the facts we accept as true. If you look at your axiom selection... why did you not take as an axiom, "the flying spaghetti monster made it so". Occam's razor is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like this question, because for me it relates to the argument or question about the nature of logic itself - the problem, for me, arises with the assumption that we need to construct a system of logic, in the first instance. This suggests we already have an idea of what *kind* of a system we would like to construct, and perhaps a system of logic that we "construct" would necessarily destroy its own epistemic status, as a consequence of our having "constructed" it, and this I believe is precisely what Wittgenstein was trying to show in his Tractatus. I think we are able to develop a fully coherent knowledge and understanding of what an internally consistent position on the nature of logic would entail - and it should also be possible for us to speak meaningfully, via propositions, about our position on the nature of logic, but these propositions would not necessarily constitute axioms or assumptions built into the system itself. Rather, they would be propositions regarding a set of ontological positions we hold, which then relate to our understanding of the nature of logic.